# Getopts in bash not selecting option

Tags: bash, getopts

I have one problem , when i select one option , for exemple  ./test.sh -f it should print "mel" but it reads all code.

How does it enter the if condition and passes with other argument ?

```
if getopts :f:d:c:v: arg ; then

if [[ "${arg}" == d ]]  ; then
    d_ID=$OPTARG
    eval d_SIZE=\$$OPTIND
else
            echo "Option -d argument missing: needs 2 args"
            echo "Please enter two args: <arg1> <arg2>"
            read d_ID d_SIZE
            echo "disc $d_ID $d_SIZE" >> $FILENAME

fi


if [[ "${arg}" == c ]] ; then
    c_NOME="$OPTARG"
    eval c_ID1=\$$OPTIND 
    eval c_ID2=\$$OPTINDplus1 
    eval c_FICHEIRO=\$$OPTINDplus2 
else
            echo "Option -c argument missing: needs 4 args"
            echo "Please enter two args: <arg1> <arg2> <arg3> <agr4>"
            read c_NOME c_ID1 c_ID2 c_FICHEIRO
            echo "raidvss $c_NOME $c_ID1 $c_ID2 $c_FICHEIRO" >> $FILENAME

fi

if [[ "${arg}" == f ]] ; then
    echo "mel"

fi


fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `getopts` parameters wrong.

```
if getopts :f:d:c:v: arg
```

means that `-f` will follow the value of parameter, like

```
-f 5
```

If you want just have `-f` (without value) you need to change it to

```
if getopts :fd:c:v: arg ; then
```

(I deleted the ':'). Also, I think you should better use `while` cycle and `case` statements.

See this example

```
while getopts fd:c:v: opt
do
   case "$opt" in
      f) echo "mel";;
      d) discFunction "$OPTARG";;
      c) otherFunction "$OPTARG";;
      v) nop;;
     \?) echo "$USAGE" >&2; exit 2;;
   esac
done    

shift `expr $OPTIND - 1`
```